# How to resolve line of code limit issue in sonarqube?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am running sonar-scanner msbuild on my vb.net project .
Since i didn't provide sonar.language properties during analysis it has analysed the .js files too. And now I am getting the error "Analyses suspended. You reached your 250000 lines of code limit allowed by your current license.Go to License page." on the sonarqube dashboard .

Now ,when i am running analysis by skipping the .js files though the analysis is successful the results are not getting reflected .

What can I do to view new results of analysis on sonarqube dashboard ?
Does deleting the project free-up that much lines of code , so that i can run analysis again ?

Also, can we use sonar.language property in command line while running analysis using scanner for msbuild ?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete one or more projecs to get below the threshold of 250'000 lines of code so that the suspending of analysis is lifted. (Or, if the project you are analysing is the only one, delete this project) That is a kind of deadlock situation, your changes (skipping the .js-file) cannot be honored by the server, because he declined taking the analysis results due to being over the threshold.

Comment: @fischermaem I have similar issue. if I delete project will SonarCloud release LOC immediately or do I need to clear analyzers?